# Apache/Glassfish recipe for running multiple apps on a single host

Tags: mod-proxy, apache-2.2, glassfish

I'm trying to set up Apache + Glassfish so that I can access two different webapps on the same physical host, differentiated by the hostname in the URL.

So if I visit http://host1.com, I'll get `app1`.  If I visit http://host2.com, I'll get `app2`. `host1` and `host2` both resolve to the same IP address.

I've been able to get this working in a *basic* way with mod_proxy and Glassfish virtualservers using [this guide](http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/2007/05/virtual-hosting-using-apache-and-glassfish/).  But the user still needs to specify the context-root for one of the apps, i.e. `http://host1.com/app1`.

**How can I set things up so that both apps appear as the "root" in their respective URLs?**

Do I need two separate Glassfish domains?

Here's the apache config I'm using:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app1
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app1
     ServerName host1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app2
     ServerName host2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was close. Here's what ended up working:

Create a 2nd domain:

- $ asadmin create-domain --portbase 5000 --profile developer mydomain
- $ asadmin start-domain mydomain

Deploy both apps to the context root in their respective domains. You specify domain by giving the admin port:

- $ asadmin deploy --contextroot "/"  target/app1.war              # domain1
- $ asadmin deploy --contextroot "/"  --port 5048 target/app2.war  # mydomain

The new domain will run on port 5080, so configure mod_proxy to use that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
     ServerName host1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:5080/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5080/
     ServerName host2.com
</VirtualHost>
```